# After Droid firmware 4.3 update, no predictive text

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4, auto-correct

I updated my droid firmware to 4.3 on Friday and had a fairly easy install ..except that my predictive text is missing in action. The setting is switched to ON (Galaxy S4 by the way) but the ribbon that usually appears above the keyboard with autocorrect suggestions is no longer there.

Can anybody help me please? I want my ribbon back. :)

Comment: What keyboard are you using? Some types of text box do not allow predictive text, for example: password fields. There are modules in Xposed framework (rooted devices only) that work around this issue. Is it completely gone from all text fields?

Comment: Hi @RossC, I'm using the standard Samsung Keyboard. The predictive text is missing from all apps that use the keyboard. Every single one. I wonder if there's a way to update the Samsung keyboard.

Comment: could you download Google keyboard from the Play Store (it's free) and see if you have the same issue. I'm loathe to recoommend the usual 'factory reset' option initially as you'll lose a lot of data. I updated my S4 to 4.3 and didn't have this issue myself. I've since rooted and put other ROMs on it. Maybe see if it is an input issue or the specific keyboard first.

Comment: @RossC, I think you could post that suggestion as an answer. I certainly think it's a fitting resolution to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue. In my case I had a bunch of words I didn't want and didn't realize there was the options to reset the learned words. Therefore, I used the system's application manager to clear cache and data. After doing this it broke the ribbon. No matter what I did I could not get it back.

I tried just about everything, but the only way I could get it back was as follows: (please note I am rooted)
1) Switch default keyboard to something else
2) Load "Titanium Backup!"
3) Browse to the "Samsung Keyboard" app and "Wipe Data!"
4) Switch back to Samsung Keyboard and the ribbon is back! :)

I'm not sure why Titanium Backup!'s "Wipe Data!" worked better than the "Clear Cache/Clear Data" from the Android settings menu. I'm wondering if clearing the data from the Android menu a second time would have worked.

I just wanted to post this information to help whoever has this issue next. It definitely can be fixed by wiping the data for just Samsung Keyboard (no factory reset needed). I just didn't narrow it down to if you need Root access, and if you need to use Titanium Backup!

Good luck!

Comment: Sadly I ended up wiping my keyboard cache + data: net result is a phone that won't start. Apparently this is a good thing because they are now replacing my battery and screen for free plus upgrading the software :)

Answer (score 1):

The thing that worked for me was downloading and using English (UK) as default.

Answer (score -1):

Try `Settings > Language and input > Samsung keyboard`. Click the `Settings icon (right side) > Predictive text`, and turn it ON.